# React to Springboot endpoint works locally but not when same setup is dockerized

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, docker

Trying to build a personal project and it's starting point was getting a React project that will fetch a springboot rest endpoint on startup to display the results in my browser. Locally it works fine and my response from the SB server of: [{"name":"course1","information":"test","id":1},{"name":"course2","information":"test2","id":2}] is displayed.

My next step was to have the same setup but dockerized and see my result in the browser again. This does not work. I see my browser display "loading" (as I coded) but in chrome tools I eventually see:

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT 172.17.0.2:8080/greeting:1`

Here is what I've tried so far:

- Verify the docker network and IP addresses
- Verify I can ping the SB container from the react container
- Install curl on the react container and I do successfully get a response from it with the data I expect
- Expose the SB container to my local host and verify I do get a response back with data
- Try different ports
- Try creating a new docker network and moving the containers over there.
- Since I have the IP hardcoded for the rest endpoint I tried localhost instead of 172.17.0.2

Im out of ideas. Below is the details for the scenario above. Let me know what I can add if needed. Thanks!

React fetch code:

```
  async componentDidMount() {
      console.log("Fetching from http://172.17.0.2:8080/greeting")
    await fetch('http://172.17.0.2:8080/greeting').then((response) => {
      if(!response.ok) throw new Error("Couldnt make the connection: " + response.status.toString());
      else return response.json();
    })
        .then((data) => {
            console.log("Testing Testing")
          this.setState({ isLoading: false, groups: data });
          console.log(data)
          console.log("DATA STORED");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('error: ' + error);
          this.setState({ requestFailed: true });
        });
  }
```

I never get to that "Testing testing" console statement

docker ps:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE      COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
34aca67969f5   frontend   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   33 minutes ago   Up 33 minutes   0.0.0.0:3001->3000/tcp   wonderful_leavitt
8c9f4023515a   demo       "java -jar /opt/app/…"   38 minutes ago   Up 38 minutes                            recursing_dubinsky
```

Docker network inspect bridge

```
        "Containers": {
            "34aca67969f5a9900fb709e76c7e95c07b9b3c89b96275ef5407a6cf9b6971a2": {
                "Name": "wonderful_leavitt",
                "EndpointID": "0cad1de1be16e1493af6da248f821b806bbeffdedff1513869a3c00a890c7a5f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "8c9f4023515a302d0d766af2b44ca900e2721be1434fb6508f3ff7df6ca6db8e": {
                "Name": "recursing_dubinsky",
                "EndpointID": "54b50219c575da857e9bf7a6d13d00fa6a1239ef250f7994a3b788c7f0099fc9",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.17.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
```

Dockerfile for springboot container:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:11
RUN mkdir /opt/app
COPY ./target/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /opt/app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/opt/app/demo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Dockerfile for react container:

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
RUN npm install react-router-dom --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Im convinced its the hard-coded IP address I have in the fetch command but not sure what to update it too. As can be seen in the docker commands I did make sure it matched the springboot server address.

Comment: You need to expose the ports on your backend container. It seems your backend is listening on `8080`. In that case, run it with `-p 8080:8080` and make the request from react to `localhost:8080/greeting`.

Comment: I did have it exposed in the Dockerfile. Adding the dockerfiles to this to be more informative. still tried doing -p 8080:8080 just in case but no change in behavior

Comment: To quote from the docker documentation: The EXPOSE instruction does not actually publish the port. It functions as a type of documentation between the person who builds the image and the person who runs the container.

Comment: Not sure what exactly you tried, but if you run the backend with `-p 8080:8080` and can't reach it on `localhost:8080` you have some other issues with your setup that's not working properly.

Comment: If I publish port 8080 in the run command I can hit it from my local machine and do get a good response back. What I want to happen is I open my browser and point at the react container. The react container calls springboot in my fetch statement above and renders the results for me.

Comment: Yes, and if you can reach it on `localhost:8080` so can your react app since it runs on your host in the browser.

Comment: So this is almost for sure an issue with the react route itself. I'll try to investigate it further over the weekend and post an update. If anyone can eyeball a problem with it and why it just wont reach the springboot service let me know.

Comment: Never found a solution to this. Going to give up and move on to trying to put my two containers into a k8's setup. Shame that I couldn't resolve it though.